# Highcharts dual yaxis scaling issue

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart with two yaxis but can't get the second data series to scale to the second axis. What am I missing?

`Example`: https://jsfiddle.net/32yugp6m/2/

Comment: Would you like to achieve something like this? Equal tick amount? Here is an example with a fixed value, but I can prepare a demo with a dynamic one if you want.  https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rgeyton4/

Comment: If I change the primary axis min to 60 then the second data set does not display. https://jsfiddle.net/893ukqpo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I see where the problem is. You have set the **series.yaxis to 1 and 2**, meanwhile, it needs to be set as **series.yAxis 0 and 1**. Notice that Axis must be started with capital letter.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8u2rhegv/

```
  series: [{
      name: 'Deg F.',
      type: 'line',
      yAxis: 0,
      data: [
        [Date.UTC(2020, 1, 22, 12, 2), 70.8],
        [Date.UTC(2020, 1, 22, 12, 1), 70.8],
        ...
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'RH',
      type: 'line',
      yAxis: 1,
      data: [
        [Date.UTC(2020, 1, 22, 12, 2), 33.4],
        [Date.UTC(2020, 1, 22, 12, 1), 33.4],
        ...
      ],
    }
  ]
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.yAxis

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about case sensitivity.